# how to hold statistical data?

Tags: php, reporting

I have to implement a reporting/statistic tool in php for one of my application. The amount of data is really huge, about 120 million records. The reports should be generated real time since the user can select many filters before generating a report, so no way to pre-generate it, let say on nightly bases.

The MySql database I use, can't handle this amount of data due the data aggregation and joins (for filtering). Even after trying to denormalize the tables it is really slow.
My question is there are any dedicated open source reporting statistics tool that I can use it from PHP? Even if it is not written in PHP but can be linked with a library.

I also read about non-sql databases but since they are not relational is really hard to do the joins on them and when comes to aggregation they are not really good (as far as I saw on mongoDB).

Thank you for your advice.

Best regards,
Feri

Comment: MapReduce on Mongo doesn't perform well yet.  Have you looked at Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

If you look for an open source reporting engine, Jasper Reports and Pentaho are the way to go, however, both run on Java and are better used loosely coupled (simply as Report Servers). There is an (partial) implementation of Jasper Reports in PHP called [PHPJasperXML](http://www.simit.com.my/?q=PHPJasperXML), depending of what you want, it may be worth to take a look at this project and use it.

Comment: Of course, if you don't mind using closed source, there may be better alternatives.